# Add Second Set of Tabs to .NET MAUI app with Shell

Tags: maui

I want to add a second set of tabs on a page that is accessed through tabs defined in `AppShell` in my .NET MAUI app. According to the documentation, `TabbedPage` is not compatible with .NET MAUI apps that use `AppShell`. How do I achieve this -- preferably with standard XAML and not through a third party solution.

Here's the look I want:

[image]

As mentioned, I define my tabs in `AppShell` like this:

```
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
   <Tab Title="Tiger" Icon="tiger.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Tiger" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Tiger}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Giraffe" Icon="giraffe.png">
       <ShellContent Route="Giraffe" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Giraffe}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Moose" Icon="moose.png">
       <ShellContent Route="Moose" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Moose}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Elephant" Icon="elephant.png">
       <ShellContent Route="Elephant" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Elephant}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

Comment: Do you mean this? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-7.0#bottom-and-top-tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to add additional `<ShellContent>` elements inside your `<Tab>` definitions as described [in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-7.0#bottom-and-top-tabs):

```xml
<FlyoutItem Title="Home" Icon="home.png">
   <Tab Title="Tiger" Icon="tiger.png">
      <ShellContent Route="Tiger" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Tiger}" />
      <ShellContent Route="Tiger2" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Tiger2}" />
      <ShellContent Route="Tiger3" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Tiger3}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Giraffe" Icon="giraffe.png">
       <ShellContent Route="Giraffe" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Giraffe}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Moose" Icon="moose.png">
       <ShellContent Route="Moose" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Moose}" />
   </Tab>
   <Tab Title="Elephant" Icon="elephant.png">
       <ShellContent Route="Elephant" ContentTemplate="{DataTemplate local: Elephant}" />
   </Tab>
</FlyoutItem>
```

I don't know if this works together with the `<FlyoutItem>`, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

You can use this auto wrapping, and get confused all you want.

But in the end, it all gets to the point, where your TabBar (that is Shell Item), contains Tabs (that are Shell Sections) and those contain a list of Shell Contents.

You can navigate between Items, and the Shell itself will provide means to navigate between Sections and Contents.

But those are not tabs.

Comment: Microsoft actually calls them **top tabs**: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/shell/tabs?view=net-maui-7.0#bottom-and-top-tabs

Comment: @ewerspej It is a reference, using business language. My answer is on technical level, pointing out significant difference between those two concepts, that Microsoft call, and often mix, by simply using the term "top and bottom tabs".

Comment: Sure, but you cannot blame others for using that same terminology. They are called tabs by Microsoft, they look like tabs and they behave like tabs from a user point of view. Under the hood, they might work differently, but that's an implementation detail and irrelevant when it comes to the goals of the OP.

Comment: @ewerspej I am not blaming anyone.